# C equivalent to the Python's struct.pack?

Tags: python, c, struct

Is there any way to acomplish, using C, the same result acomplished with the function `struct.pack(...)` from Python? I am trying write with C a code originally written in Python, and this code has a line like that:

```
header = (struct.pack("<L", ver) + prev_block.decode('hex')[::-1]
          + mrkl_root.decode('hex')[::-1]
          + struct.pack("<LLL", time_, bits, nonce))
```

which I want rewrite in C.

**UPDATE**

I had put this preliminary C code in motion:

```
char* ver_pack;
char* prev_block_pack;
char* mkrl_root_pack;
char* time_pack;
char* bits_pack;
char* nonce_pack;
char* header = malloc(strlen(ver_pack)+strlen(prev_block_pack)+strlen(mkrl_root_pack)+strlen(time_pack)+strlen(bits_pack)+strlen(nonce_pack));
strcpy(header, ver_pack);
strcat(header, prev_block_pack);
strcat(header, mkrl_root_pack);
strcat(header, time_pack);
strcat(header, bits_pack);
strcat(header, nonce_pack);
```

now I need to figure out the values for each one of the elements in the header, which are:

```
int ver
char* prev_block
char* mrkl_root
unsigned int time_
unsigned int bits
unsigned int nonce
```

Comment: try this code: const char *string = "\x11\x11\x11\x11";
puts(string);

Comment: according to this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_puts.htm, `puts` only print the string in the stdout? I need append it to this other string `header`.

Comment: Have you allocated the memory for `header` yet?

Comment: You typically `memcpy` into consecutive locations of a memory block.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yes (see the update)

Comment: Your allocation uses the length of unallocated arrays, so that's a bad thing. You already know how large most of the fields are.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams but I not using unallocated arrays, I just trying figure out what the values for each one of elements (in the python code was used `struct.pack(...)` and `.decode(...)` functions)

Comment: The reason C doesn't have a way to do this in strings is because it gives you direct access to the data, and it doesn't need a text based workaround. You can memcpy blocks of data based on known lengths. Instead of making a bits_pack, you memcpy bits directly, using sizeof(bits). Additionally strlen is obviously wrong because binary data will contain zeroes as data. If you try to use strlen you are using a variable length that won't work to find a length you already know from the data type itself.

Comment: same for strcpy and strcat. You cannot use them for binary data unless you can guarantee that the data never has zeroes, and also has additional zeroes to tell your string functions where to stop.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want C code for this struct, not a generic parser based on the format codes used by a python function? A hex dump of this header would help for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is you need to understand is that char* is not a string type. Because you decode hex, you should expect to have any value, including several zeroes. Therefore you need to store the length separately for the binary data.

Of course, it would be much easier in C++, with std::string, which would be much more like python strings (disclaimer, I am a c++ programmer).

Second, do you want to store this buffer, or just stream it? It's much easier if you just stream this to a file (or whatever) by writing these pieces with known size. That's what I'd do in c++ if I wanted to put header in an std::string. And that's what I'd do if I were writing a file in C. Just call fwrite instead of memcpy.

Storing the header in memory means you again must store the length, because it contains arbitrary binary data, and as before, it might have the null character as part of the data. Here's a sample:

```
int length = sizeof(ver) + prev_block_length + mrkl_root_length + sizeof(time_) + sizeof(bits) + sizeof(nonce);
char * header = (char*)malloc(length);

char * p = header; // placeholder which we advance as we write
memcpy(p, &ver, sizeof(ver)); p += sizeof(ver);
memcpy(p, prev_block, prev_block_length); p += prev_block_length;
memcpy(p, mrkl_root, mrkl_root_length); p += mrkl_root_length;
memcpy(p, &time_, sizeof(time_)); p += sizeof(time_);
memcpy(p, &bits, sizeof(bits)); p += sizeof(bits);
memcpy(p, &nonce, sizeof(nonce)); p += sizeof(nonce);

// and eventually you must free (another good reason to just stream it)
free(header);
```